# Run loop in TCL shell background

Tags: background, tcl

I'm looking for a way to run a loop in TCL shell background (meaning - an infinite loop calling some function), but I can't find a way to do it.

The proc is a simple proc releasing all possible licenses from the user (we have a shortage of licenses here at work and we constantly fighting who's going to get them).

The loop itself is simple:

```
while {1} { 
      after 60000
      clr_lic
}
```

But how can I make it run in the background so I'll be able to run other commands as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you running an event loop? If you are, you can do this with the `every` procedure:

```
proc every {ms script} {
    after $ms [info level 0]
    uplevel "#0" $script
    # Double quotes just for syntax highlighting…
}

every 60000 clr_lic
```

Otherwise, things get awkward: you'd have to think about spinning up a thread or a subprocess and… well, it all gets a lot more awkward as then you're in a strongly segregated context and have to do a lot more work (well, usually).

---

When testing the code above, I used this:

```
every 500 {
    puts "Hi there, world!"
}
vwait forever;  # Conventional way to run the event loop in tclsh
```

And I got quite a lot of messages written out; it's flexible and easy.

Comment: Hi Donal. thanks for the procedure, it works great. but is there a way I stop it? it's like the broom from fantasia :)

Comment: Not with the simple version. The Tcler's Wiki page on `every`, http://wiki.tcl.tk/9299, has cancellable versions.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. you've been a real help.

Answer (score -1):

Try appending an ampersand (&) when invoking your script. This will run it in background and you're be able to run any command you like.

Comment: your answer is correct, if we were talking about a regular shell, but this is tcl shell we're talking about, not some application I need to run in the background (for which Ctrl-z and `bg` would have served).